# Info panel block tab header when view less info in StackOverflow profile

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was viewing StackOverflow profile page, then click `less info` next to the name.
When the info panel finish resizing, it block over half of the tab header below.

Here is a screenshot: [image: StackOverflow profile less info block tabs' header]

I also checked some other sites.

- Android: good
- SuperUser, Meta: block parts of the top of the tabs' header

Comment: Which browser do you use? Does this happen in all of them?

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Mac. Just re-checked it with Safari, Firefox & Opera: everything ok.

Comment: Probably a bug that's on its way to be fixed. It works in Chrome Dev on OS X.

Comment: I notice that if I click `less info` and refresh the page then everything's ok. Turn out that this bug only happen when toggle from `more` to `less` with chrome

Comment: Reproduced with Chrome 19.0 on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to repro this. The fix will be in the next production build.